# How to use multiple workspaces correctly in golang in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, go, environment-variables, ubuntu-16.04

I had installed go-1.6 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I also had set up two different workspaces and the $GOPATH by specifying the location of both the workspaces in it.

But one of the workspaces(primary or main workspace) is working correctly while the other one(secondary workspace) is not working. I wish to use the secondary workspace for practising web app development in golang and the primary one for my projects. Both these workspaces have different packages in them as I am using them for different purposes. While working with the secondary workspace, I am getting errors like 'package not found' when I import packages in my programs . The 'go build' tool is looking for those packages in the primary workspace but they are present in secondary workspace. I am using Atom editor by GitHub.

Even when I install packages using 'go get', the packages are installed in the primary workspace.

The 'go environment variables' are as follows :-

```
gkv@GKVInnovations:~$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/gkv/Desktop/goWorkspace:/home/gkv/Desktop/Business/Backend"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.6"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.6/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Location of the primary workspace :- /home/gkv/Desktop/goWorkspace

Location of the secondary workspace :- /home/gkv/Desktop/Business/Backend

Please help me to resolve this issue and improve my workflow!

Comment: from the [GOPATH documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable): "Go searches each directory listed in GOPATH to find source code, but new packages are always downloaded into the first directory in the list". Don't use multiple paths, just change your GOPATH when you want to change "workspaces"

Comment: But making multiple workspaces is possible and there must be any way to resolve this issue. I just want a way to get rid of this problem. Any kind of help from you and Stack Overflow community would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "making multiple workspaces is possible"? What you're seeing is the expected behavior for the `go` tools.

Comment: Honestly I would just use separate user accounts if you must maintain separate folders

Comment: A workspace is defined by the value of GOPATH.  To use multiple workspaces, one uses different values for GOPATH.

Comment: I have given two values for GOPATH. Still I am not able to use multiple workspaces correctlly. Then what is wrong? Is it possible that when I change workspace, GOPATH also changes?

Comment: You have shown one value for GOPATH, `/home/gkv/Desktop/goWorkspace:/home/gkv/Desktop/Business/Backend`.  What's the other value that you use?  I suggest starting with single directory workspaces (example: `GOPATH=/home/gkv/Desktop/goWorkspace`).  Using multiple directories in a workspace is an advanced feature.

Comment: ':' is separating the locations of the two workspaces or the two values of GOPATH

Comment: The value `/home/gkv/Desktop/goWorkspace:/home/gkv/Desktop/Business/Bac‌​kend` specifies a single workspace that uses two directories.  It does not specify two workspaces.

Comment: Ok! Then how can I give two values to GOPATH and specify two workspaces?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Atom, which makes it harder to change GOPATH.

> Go searches each directory listed in GOPATH to find source code, but new packages are always downloaded into the first directory in the list.

From https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable

> Even though the GOPATH may be a list of directories, it is generally correct and sufficient to use a single GOPATH for all Go code on your machine. Since all packages retrieved with "go get" have a unique URL (and thus a unique path on disk), having more than one GOPATH is almost never necessary when building with the Go tool.

From https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH#use-a-single-gopath

Comment: Then how can I get rid of this problem? Is it a bug in GO?

Comment: You cannot use multiple workspaces correctly without changing GOPATH. As the second quote says, there is no need for two workspaces. Use the vendor folder if you need to customize dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I use go for a client with specific packages and personally on lighter project. It's on the same computer.
I mostly use go get for both of them.

By default I have an `export GOPATH=~/path/to/pro` in my `~/.bashrc`.
And when I want to work on my personal project, I `export GOPATH=~/path/to/perso`.

As I use multiple desktops view (workspace) in unity, I let 1 workspace with a terminal with the right GOPATH in it and tinker in it